# Particular example of comma after but

Tags: commas

I saw an american person (native) write this sentence.

Random stuf about him not not being able to make it in time and period. Then new sentence

"But, this time, George does arrive and they head to..."

I've read here that but after conjuction should not be used, does it mean it's wrong what this native person wrote?
The main issue is that he starts a new sentence with but, something that was not discussed here.
If it's possible to write comma after but I could make up sentences like this one:

"But, back then, while he waited, she was kissing Peter." Would it be correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I had already read that thread (that's the one I'm talking about when I said "I've read here"). My question still remains. I've also read in an english book that sometimes (very rarely) the use of comma after but is allowed, but there were no examples, so I'm inquiring if this sentence may be one of those examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ohh I thought it was another thread, yes, that one's new to me and it helps me XD. But I still need someone to tell me if the sentence the native speaker wrote can therefore be considered correct.

Comment: For example, someone telling me that both are equally correct ("But, this time, George does arrive and they head to..." and "But this time, George does arrive and they head to...") would solve my doubt

Comment: You can consider _this time_ as a parenthetical and include the commas (I wouldn't normally use brackets or dashes here), _or_ you could say that the sentence flows well without signalling 'this time' as a parenthetical, leaving out the commas. You have the choice: would you like to emphasise _this time_ or not.